# SQL timestamp not converting to OffsetDateTime

Tags: java, jdbctemplate, sql-timestamp, offsetdatetime

I have a sql timestamp that is being returned from a query in java. I need this date as an OffsetDateTime type, but my attempts to parse it have failed. I've tried the following. What other steps do I need to take?

I'm iterating through the sql response list from my jdbcTemplate. I'm able to access other string rows just fine, but when I try to include this code the query fails. date_column refers to the column in the table and my query is returning the data. It's just not being transformed to OffsetDateTime.

`DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;`
`OffsetDateTime dateColumn = OffsetDateTime.parse(row.get("date_column").toString(), dateTimeFormatter);`

The row.get response returns this date format `2023-07-17 12:22:02.626948`

Comment: Use a debugger to check what the String.valueOf(row.get("date_column")) is returning. Is the string actually compatible with the formatter? What error did you find in the stacktrace?

Comment: If you have something like 2023-07-17 12:22:02.626948, then you don't have an offset. Do you assume that the time is at UTC?

Comment: The value you produced doesn't match the format of `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` (which uses `T` as a separator and expects an offset). In addition, you should change how you populate `row` so you get a `java.time` object directly, not what I guess is a `java.sql.Timestamp`: if your column is a `TIMESTAMP`, then you'd use `java.time.LocalDateTime`, if the column is a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, you can get a `java.time.OffsetDateTime` **directly** (assuming your JDBC driver is JDBC 4.2 compliant).

Comment: As an aside, if you do have a `java.sql.Timestamp`, you can convert it to a `java.time.LocalDateTime` directly with `toLocalDateTime()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in the db you don't have stored the offset (as you say, you are returning something like `2023-07-17 12:22:02.626948`), then you can obtain a `OffsetDateTime` only with some assumptions. For example, the following snippet will work if you assume that the LocalDateTime is at UTC:

```
String s = "2023-07-17 12:22:02.626948";
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.nnnnnn");
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(s, dateTimeFormatter);
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = localDateTime.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```